# Where are the ACF fields in the new Woocommerce interface

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

Woocommerce recently changed their interface to a more modern one.

But since then, I can't find where my ACF fields are in the product edition page.

The ACF group is correctly assigned to the product post type.

I didn't find any information on this, most tutorials are still on the old interface.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: Welcome! This question really belongs on the ACF or WooCommerce support forums.

Comment: You may need to check in "Screen Options" tab (located near up right page corner), if your field group is enabled for display in the current product you are editing/adding.